# Change deployed objects using publish profiles

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to find a way to have a database object change based on the publish profile used, or a sqlcmd variable.  Specifically, if I deploy the database project to Server A & B; on Server A I want one version of a stored procedure, on Server B I want a different version of the stored procedure.  For dependency reasons the stored procedure must have the same name on both servers.  I know of a way to do this using post deployment scripts and dynamic sql.  I am looking for a better option.

Comment: What do you mean by a better option? What's wrong with the two ways you already know of for doing this?

Comment: I'd like to avoid hiding a database object in a post deployment script.  They way I know how to do it may not be the best way so I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: Partial projects or whatever they're called now. Create one main project with everything except that stored proc. Create sub-projects with the different versions of the stored procs and a DB Reference to the main proj w/ option set to include those objects. Deploy the sub-projects. See this for more details: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/03/10/deployment-of-client-specific-database-code-using-ssdt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it is actual for question starter, however it might help someone. You can do following:

1. Create variable, for example $(DeployType) and set it to unique
   value in all publishing configs
2. Alter your database with following code:

.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE p_test 
  AS
 BEGIN
 IF '$(DeployType)' = 'Production'
  BEGIN
 /*Your code for production database*/
 END
 IF '$(DeployType)' = 'Dev'
  BEGIN
 /*Your code for devdatabase*/
  END
  END
```

In that case it supposed to be exactly what you want. With views/functions you can do something like:

```
CREATE VIEW v_test AS
SELECT 1
FROM table 
WHERE '$(DeployType)' = 'Production'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1
FROM table2 
WHERE '$(DeployType)' = 'Dev'
```

The performance is not supposed to decrease as optimizer checks WHERE condition and see that 1 part of union will allways be NULL so it does not execute it.